# Restricting user access to a particular page - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got this brilliant piece of code that restricts access to the wp-admin login page unless the user logged in is an admin to the site:

```
add_action( 'init', 'blockusers_init' );
  function blockusers_init() {
    if ( is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) &&
    ! ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
  }
}
```

I want to add another function that restricts access and performs the same redirect to my home page BUT for a specific page of my site. 
But this isn't working:

```
add_action( 'init', 'blockusers_init' );
  function blockusers_init() {
    if ( is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) &&
    ! ( defined( 'mysite.co.uk/shop' ) && DOING_AJAX ) ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
  }
}
```

And I'm not surpised by that but I was hoping somebody had to correct code to perform this function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your header.php file to check if they're on the page and if they're an admin or not

```
if(is_page(PAGE_ID)){
    current_user_can( 'manage_options' ){
        ---do redirect here or whatever else---
    }
}
```

You can also create load the function via the init action like you did.